# Determine empty row based on first four columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a UserForm in Excel to move content from textbox 1 to first empty row on sheet 2. Below command works fine but I would like to consider an empty row only if the first three columns are empty, not all columns (the others columns have some information).

How can I adjust it?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim emptyRow As Long

'Make Sheet2 active
With Sheets("Sheet2")

    'Determine emptyRow
    emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("A:A")) + 1

    'Transfer information

    .Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = TextBox1.Value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try this:**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim x&, i&, emptyRow&
    emptyRow = 0
    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        For x = 1 To 3
            i = .Cells(Rows.Count, x).End(xlUp).Row
            If emptyRow < i + 1 Then emptyRow = i + 1
        Next x
        .Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = TextBox1.Value
    End With
End Sub
```

***test:***

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Look from the bottom up.

```
emptyRow = application.max(.cells(rows.count, "A").end(xlup).row, _ 
                           .cells(rows.count, "B").end(xlup).row, _
                           .cells(rows.count, "C").end(xlup).row) + 1
```

Comment: Can the OP do (rows.count, "A:C") to find the first row of A B and C empty? Or is the `, 4)` part doing that

Comment: @MatthewD Rows.Count does not check whether anything is inside of a cell to count it - it simply tells you the size of your range. ie: Range("A:A").Rows.Count equals the total number of rows in a workbook.

Comment: @Grade 'Eh' Bacon Thanks. I need to spend some time leaning the .max

Comment: If there are supposed to be 3 empty rows at the top then the first available row would be 4. If there is nothing in column A, start at row 4; if there is anything in column A start at the first blank cell.

Comment: @MatthewD If you look at Scott's answer above, it has a similar method to what you're looking for, using the native Excel function CountA.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim emptyRow As Long, x as Long

'Make Sheet2 active
With Sheets("Sheet2")

    'Determine emptyRow
    x = 0

    Do 

         x = x +1

         emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("A" & x & ":C" & x))

    Loop Until emptyRow = 0

    'Transfer information
    .Cells(x, 1).Value = TextBox1.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Test the value of those columns for each row until you find the blank one.

You can probably do it with a find also but i'm not sure how off the top of my head.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Dim emptyRow As Long

    Dim lrow As Long
    lrow = 1

    ws.Activate
    'Loop through the rows
    Do While lrow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.count

        'Test for an empty row
        If ws.Range("A" & lrow).Value = "" And ws.Range("B" & lrow).Value = "" And ws.Range("C" & lrow).Value = "" Then
            emptyRow = lrow
            Exit Do
        End If

    lrow = lrow + 1
    Loop

    ws.Range("A" & emptyRow).Value = TextBox1.Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim emptyRow As Long
Dim row1  As Long, row2 As Long, row3 As Long

'Make Sheet2 active
With Sheets("Sheet2")

'Determine emptyRow
row1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count,1).End(XlUp).Row + 1
row2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count,2).End(XlUp).Row + 1
row3 = .Cells(.Rows.Count,3).End(XlUp).Row + 1

If row1 = row2 And row1 = row3 Then

emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("A:A")) + 1

Else

    If row1 >= row2 And row1 >= row3 Then

    emptyRow = row1

    Elseife row2 >= row3 Then

    emptyRow = row2

    Else

    emptyRow = row3

    End If

End If

'Transfer information

.Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = TextBox1.Value
```

So what this does, is that it will check if the last row in column A, B and C are the same, and if not, the emptyRow is set on the "largest" last row of columns A, B or C.
I hope, that this is what you where looking for. Else ignore this post.